# lapply function in R: delete columns with repeated names on the rows

Tags: r, database, lapply

I am calculating the quantiles, trimean, etc. of my data frame

```
table1 <- data.frame(
  "Q25"= stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], quantile, prob = c(0.25))),
  "Q50"= stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], quantile, prob = c(0.50))),
  "Q75"= stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], quantile, prob = c(0.75))), 
  "IQR" = stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], IQR)),
  "Trimean" = stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], trimean)),
  "Skewness" = stack(lapply(database_PE[4:7], skewness)))
```

The output is the following as I expected:

```
  Q25.values             Q25.ind Q50.values             Q50.ind Q75.values             Q75.ind IQR.values             IQR.ind Trimenan.values
1       23.1        Air.Temp.Max       30.6        Air.Temp.Max       37.8        Air.Temp.Max       14.7        Air.Temp.Max          30.525
2        7.1        Air.Temp.Min       13.5        Air.Temp.Min       21.0        Air.Temp.Min       13.9        Air.Temp.Min          13.775
3       14.4       Air.Temp.Mean       21.9       Air.Temp.Mean       29.9       Air.Temp.Mean       15.5       Air.Temp.Mean          22.025
4        0.0 Precipitation.Total        0.0 Precipitation.Total        0.0 Precipitation.Total        0.0 Precipitation.Total           0.000
         Trimenan.ind Skewness.values        Skewness.ind
1        Air.Temp.Max        34.11678        Air.Temp.Max
2        Air.Temp.Min        34.56093        Air.Temp.Min
3       Air.Temp.Mean        34.07599       Air.Temp.Mean
4 Precipitation.Total        39.82098 Precipitation.Total
```

Nevertheless, I am trying to find a way to take out the repeated columns with row names Air.Temp.Max, Air.Temp.Min, Air.Temp.Mean and Precipitation.Total. What should I write in the lapply function to take out these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one `lapply` call and bind the dataset.

```
data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(database_PE[4:7], function(x) 
  c(quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)), IQR(x), trimean(x), skewness(x))))
names(data) <- c('Q25', 'Q50', 'Q75', 'IQR', 'trimness', 'skewness')
```

This will keep rownames as rownames, if you want it as separate column do :

```
data$rowname <- rownames(data)
```

Comment: How can I add in that do.call function the na.rm = TRUE?

Comment: I think `do.call` doesn't need `na.rm` but you need to add it for individual functions like `IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)`